# How to retain the sort order of primefaces datatable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my project I am using a ViewScoped bean and I have two pages one is main page and the other details page.

In the main page I have a primefaces datatable with sorting and filtering functionality.
The datatable has a link in each row. If I sort a column, then it works properly. If I click on a link in the main page, then it will go to the details page showing the details of the corresponding row. In the details page I have a back button. If I click on it, it will take me back to the main page, but the sort order is not retained in the datatable.

I need to retain the sort order. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Any inputs for this question?

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is pretty old, but I just worked on this so I figured I'd share my solution for the future.

We're using PrimeFaces 3.5

This was only implemented on a lazy loading table and never implemented on an in-memory table. The biggest difference that might exist is you would need to store the column type (Class) for an in-memory table.

First of all, you need some sort of SessionScoped controller that you can save the sort state to. You'll need to store two states: sort column and sort order (ascending/descending).

Secondly, bind the p:datatable to an object in your ViewScoped controller (`binding="#{viewController.datatable}"`), and implement the basic getter and setter for it. In the setter method, I have this:

```
public void setDatatable(DataTable datatable) {
    ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = ExpressionFactory.newInstance();
    ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
    if(!datatableInitialized) {
        if(getSessionController().getSortState() == null) {
            datatable.setValueExpression("sortBy", expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, DEFAULT_SORT_COLUMN, Object.class));
            datatable.setSortOrder(DEFAULT_SORT_DIRECTION);
        } else {
            SortState state = getSessionController().getSortState();
            datatable.setValueExpression("sortBy", expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, state.getValueExpression(), Object.class));
            datatable.setSortOrder(state.getDirection());
        }
        datatableInitialized = true;
    }
    this.datatable = datatable;
}
```

The important bits are the setValueExpression lines, the second parameter of the createValueExpression method requires the JSF style expression, ie: `#{pojo.stuff}`. Also notice how I'm just using Object.class as the type, I believe I can get away with this because the table is lazy loaded and I'm handling all the sorting myself in the LazyDataModel implementation.

Third, add the sorting event to the datatable:

```
<p:ajax event="sort" listener="#{viewController.sortListener}" />
```

and the listener in the controller:

```
public void sortListener(SortEvent event) {
    SortState state = new SortState();
    state.setValueExpression(event.getSortColumn().getValueExpression("sortBy").getExpressionString());
    state.setDirection(event.isAscending() ? "ascending" : "descending");
    getSessionController().setOpportunitiesSortState(state);
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

5 years later, PrimeFaces supports this feature out of the box. Starting from version `6.0.10`, PrimeFaces added the [`TableState` feature](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/tableState.xhtml). It will allow your DataTable to maintain its state even after leaving the page.

As stated in the docs, all you need to do is enable the `multiViewState` attribute on the `DataTable`.

```
<p:dataTable id="tableStateTable" value="#{view.items}" var="item" 
             multiViewState="true">
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```