# primefaces datatable getting refreshed on page change

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces datatable which has a list of values being displayed. And every row has a Open  button which navigates to other page for details and on the same page i have a back button which takes me page to the previous visited page. so it comes to the datatable page which gets refreshed to the original state...it does not maintain the records which the user had searched. My Managed Bean is in viewscope. I want to the records to be maintained even if the user navigates to other pages and comes back to the same page. I tried making the managed bean Session scoped that solves the issue but on page refresh the datatable does not get refreshed .even if we do a Control+refresh it still maintains the same records

Comment: An alternative: put the page with details in a dialog instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727900/how-to-retain-the-sort-order-of-primefaces-datatable

Comment: What scope has the managed bean that holds your data?